# LD_LIBRARY_PATH side effects

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ld

I am having strange side effects on changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

When I append a path containing a library, e.g. :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/my_path/lib
```

Then, everything becomes unbelievably slow. For example, a simple `ls` can be 10 seconds long.

`ldd` output is exactly the same before and after the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` change and I tried to debug the execution of the slow `ls` with `strace` : I get the exact same execution in both cases. The execution does not even get stuck during the execution of `ls` (since `strace` does not output anything during the 10-second lag and then suddenly perfectly executes `ls`). So I thought it could come from my shell, but this is the same, running `strace` on my bash and executing `ls` in both cases gives me the same `strace` output : the shell executes `ls` and wait for the end of its execution (the last `strace` output before the lag `strace` is `waitpid(...)`). So I guess something wrong happens between the the launch of `ls` and its execution, like if it was a kernel-level issue. It really acts like if a `sleep` was made on `ls` (0 cpu usage).

During the lag, my CPU and network activity are perfectly normal...

Note that the library in the new LD path does not conflict with any "standard library", so it does not disturb `ls` in my example.

So I am interesting in deeper explanations about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` side effects or how to deeply debug my example.

Comment: Good question.  I have used `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and have never seen such behavior, yet your observation seems both isolated and clear.  Interesting.

Comment: `export LD_DEBUG=all` and `man 8 ld.so`

Comment: propably obvious but "ldd $(which ls)" may give a clue if ls uses anything from LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try removing the library file from the new path? Or replacing it by a copy of a standard library?

Comment: @thb @Thomas @Matthias : I found what was causing the lag but without understanding why (thanks to `LD_DEBUG=all`): there was a path which didn't exist in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, this path was on a distant server... BUT there are other paths on the same server and they absolutely don't cause any problem...

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I append a path containing a library_, and in your comment: _there was a path which didn't exist_; are you speaking of the same path at the end of LD_LIBRARY_PATH? If not, was the path which didn't exist present in LD_LIBRARY_PATH before you appended `:/my_path/lib` and didn't cause the problem then?

Comment: If another path in the variable is causing the delay, should this condition not have been evident prior to your amendment to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 3):

This post is quit old, so I don't know if you find already a solution. Anyway, I don't know if this may help, but in most modern GNU/Linux systems, **the use of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is deprecated** and discouraged.

Therefore I have a couple of suggestions:

1. if you want to continue using it, try first by pre-pending instead of appending your library path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This should help if there is something that takes long time to scan the path in previous library directories.
2. Use LDCONFIG system, which is the (new) *proper way* of using LD directories nowadays. You simply have to add the path to your library in */etc/ld.so.conf* file, or better, add a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ which contains the path to your library (it will be sourced if there is an include directive in */etc/ld.so.conf*, which is usually the case by default). Then run `sudo ldconfig` to update the system LD search path.

I hope this help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what else is on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or library you are trying to add or what program you are running, but you are probably better off writing a wrapper script to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH just for the program that needs the extra library so that your system functions like `ls` aren't affected.

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my_path/lib
program_name
```

Create file and `chmod +x wrapper_name`